# Hadamard variational formula Evans chapter 6 problem 15

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

This is Evans' chapter 6 problem 15.

> Consider a family of smooth, bounded domains $U(\tau) \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ that depend smoothly upon the parameter $\tau \in \mathbb{R}$. As $\tau$ changes, each point on $\partial U(\tau)$ moves with velocity $v$.
>
> For each $\tau$, we consider eigenvector $\lambda= \lambda(\tau)$ and corresponding eigenfunction $w = w(x,\tau) $ such that $-\Delta w = \lambda w$ in $U(\tau)$, $w=0$ on $\partial U$, normalized so that $||w||_{L^{2}(U(\tau))} = 1$. Suppose $\lambda, w$ are smooth.
>
> Prove Hadamard's variational formular $\partial_{\tau}\lambda = -\int_{\partial U(\tau)} \left|\frac{\partial w}{\partial \nu} \right|^{2} v \cdot \nu$ where $v \cdot \nu$ is normal velocity of $\partial U(\tau)$.

Using hints on evans, I get

> $$\frac{\partial}{\partial\tau}\int_{U(\tau)}\lambda dx = \int_{\partial U}\lambda v \cdot \nu + \int_{U(\tau)}\lambda_{\tau}$$

But I don't know how to prove the rest. Could you give some idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Evans's hint is the Leibniz rule:
$$ \frac{d}{d\tau}\int_{U(\tau)} F(x,\tau) dx = \int_{\partial U(\tau)} F(x,\tau) \, v\cdot \nu \, dS(\tau) + \int_{U} F_\tau(x,\tau) \, dx,$$
where $v$ is the velocity of the boundary $\partial U$ with respect to $\tau$ and $\nu$ is the outward unit normal. (See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_transport_theorem) or [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) for details, but the details aren't too important for the problem.)

Based on the hint and the variational formula, we should probably write $\lambda(\tau)$ as an integral and differentiate with respect to $\tau$. This can be accomplished in two ways:
$$ \lambda(\tau) = \int_U w(-\Delta w) \, dx = \int_U |\nabla w|^2 \, dx. $$

Now apply the Leibniz rule to the above equation. Differentiating the first equality gives you some useful information when dealing with the second equality. Use the identity $-\Delta w = \lambda w$ and multivariable integration by parts (see Appendix C in Evans, for example) as needed. The answer should come out.

Another note is that since $w$ vanishes on $\partial U$, the gradient $\nabla w$ is perpendicular to $\partial U$ and thus parallel to the unit normal $\nu$. Therefore, the $|\frac{\partial w}{\partial \nu}|^2$ in Hadamard's formula is just $|\nabla w|^2$.

More about the formula: [Hadamard's Formula Inside and Out](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10957-010-9681-6#page-1)

Comment: $\lambda ' =\partial\tau \int_U \omega(-\Delta \omega) dx =\int_{\partial U} \omega(-\Delta \omega) v\cdot \nu dS + \int_U \partial_\tau (\lambda \omega^2) dx= \lambda' +2\lambda \int_U \omega(\partial_x\omega \partial_t x + \partial_t \omega) $. Then, I can't go on.